# Intval in Twig Template

Tags: symfony, twig

The problem is very short.

I have got an array with integer keys, and parameter which is the string. I want to get element of that array by using that parameter.

How to get in Twig `intval - (int)"32"` of `{{ variable }}` where `variable == (string) "32";`?

Comment: Are you sure this isnt application logic and should be done before entering twig?

Answer (score 29):

There are filters in twig. One of them is this:

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/number_format.html

```
{{ variable|number_format }}
```

if you are doing math on a string, it will automatically cast to an interger anyways, however!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but here you are inversing OP's problem. `{{ variable|number_format }}` is converting an int to string, which yes, solves the problem, but the other way around...

Comment: I do not believe this is correct. I just tested it and "number_format" filter does not convert string to int.

Comment: as @xDaizu mentioned correctly, this is converting a float into a string. See http://php.net/number_format as well as the twig function is just a wrapper

Comment: You are correct. My answer assumes that the problem occured while *displaying* the value, not while applying logic to it.

Comment: This is actually the right answer, `number_format` converts a string to a number.

Comment: It partly works. It converts a string into a _numeric_ string (but it's still technically a string).

Comment: Lindsey D and others are right, it converts `variable` to `string`. In the Twig documentation they state "It is a wrapper around PHP's number_format function", which in fact returns `string`. [Ref](https://secure.php.net/number_format).

Comment: The function's purpose is to format a number, which means there will be a string as the result and moreover you can get it with thousands separator, e.g. instead of expected 1000 you'll get '1,000'

Answer (score 9):

You can access a value of an array using a variable as the key like this: `myArray[myKey]`. It doesn't matter whether the array keys are integers (e.g. `32`) or corresponding strings (`"32"`), or whether `myKey` is an integer or a string. All of these combinations should work ([see TwigFiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/p8e5o5)):

```
{% set myArray = {
    1:   'first',
    '2': 'second',
} %}

{% set keyOneInt = 1 %}
{% set keyOneStr = '1' %}
{% set keyTwoInt = 2 %}
{% set keyTwoStr = '2' %}

{# These all print 'first' #}
{{ myArray.1 }}
{{ myArray[1] }}
{{ myArray['1'] }}
{{ myArray[keyOneInt] }}
{{ myArray[keyOneStr] }}

{# These all print 'second' #}
{{ myArray.2 }}
{{ myArray[2] }}
{{ myArray['2'] }}
{{ myArray[keyTwoInt] }}
{{ myArray[keyTwoStr] }}
```

On the third line of the above code, the string key `'2'` is actually cast to integer `2`, like [PHP's documentation of arrays](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) states:

> Strings containing valid decimal integers, unless the number is
> preceded by a *+* sign, will be cast to the integer type. E.g. the key
> *"8"* will actually be stored under *8*. On the other hand "*08"* will not be
> cast, as it isn't a valid decimal integer.

If for some reason you need an integer, you can cast a string to an int by performing math operations on it – e.g. `variable * 1` (= `"32" * 1`) or `variable + 0` (= `"32" + 0`).

Comment: Adding + 0 was the only solution that converted the string to an integer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous solution is good if you want to get just a intval. `format_number` add decimal to string. This solution is maybe the worst.

What worked for me is

Add a custom [twig function filter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html#create-the-extension-class) just like :

```
public function getFilters(): array
{
    return [
        new TwigFilter('force_to_int', fn ($value) => intval($value))
    ];
}
```

Use it like :

```
{{ str_to_convert|force_to_int }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59213377/918602).

```
{{ 0 + myNumber }} // returns int(3)
```