# Converting a String to Float in Twig

Tags: twig

Basically, I have set a parameter called "rating" that's equal to a product.DETAILS.STAR_RATING which is a value imported from a database-driven field which happens to be a string, I want to multiply this value by 20 but since "rating" is a string I cannot multiply it.

How do I convert the string to a float value?

```
{% set rating = product.DETAILS.STAR_RATING %} 
  {{rating * 20}}
```

Comment: Sure you can, it's `PHP`. It will typecast it for you. See [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/i0is6i). What isn't working for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simple way, maybe strange but...

```
{% set rating = 0 + product.DETAILS.STAR_RATING %} 
{{ rating * 20}}
```

Comment: This is not necessary as you could even multiply two strings [`{{ '42' * '20' }}`](https://twigfiddle.com/i0is6i/2)

Comment: @DarkBee Yep that's true, it wasn't some (or long) times ago. So please send your comment as an answer in order to help (better) the other viewers

Comment: Already stated that behavior in the comment. Question should be closed as being not reproducible

Comment: You saved me. I was using number_format to show decimal upto 2 places, but it is converting it into string. But just adding with 0 makes it decimal again.